# converting a string passed from unix shell to a node program to a javascript-formatted one?

Tags: node.js, bash

I'm using a bash script to send an argument to a node app like so:

```
testString="\nhello\nthere"
node ./myNodeScript.js $testString
```

The trouble comes when I use `testString` inside the node program after capturing it as `process.argv[2]` -- rather than expand the `\n` characters to newlines node prints them literally.  I need a way to tell node to convert the argument to a javascript string, respecting the formatting characters.  Is there a way to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

Try to avoid confusing literal linefeeds and literal backslash followed by literal `n`.

If you want the string you pass to have linefeeds, you should ignore JavaScript string literal syntax and just pass the linefeeds as linefeeds:

```
$ cat myNodeScript.js
console.log("Node was passed this: " + process.argv[2])

$ cat myBashScript
testString='
hello
there'
printf 'Bash passes this: %s\n' "$testString"
node myNodeScript.js "$testString"

$ bash myBashScript
Bash passes this: 
hello
there
Node was passed this: 
hello
there
```

Arguments should contain data (linefeed) while script files should contain code (quoted linefeed or expanded `\n` as appropriate in the language). When you make sure not to confuse code and data, you can trivially handle both backslash-en and linefeeds in the same string with no surprises:

```
testString='
"\nhello\nthere" is JavaScript syntax for:
hello
there'
```

There are ways to express this on a single line in bash using `\n` for linefeeds and `\\n` for backslash-en, you just need to make sure that it remains as code, and doesn't accidentally make it into the variable as data.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
testString=$( printf "\nhello\nthere")
node ./myNodeScript.js "$testString"
```

And let me know if it works?

Comment: unfortunately it didn't add newlines.